# Calling a css from a js using Symfony 2

Tags: javascript, css

I have this gallery the designer handed to me, and I have to put it on my twig. The thing is the slider is not working. This is the code (the js with the problem):

```
$(function () {
    var demo1 = $("#demo1").slippry({
        transition: "fade",
        useCSS: true,
        speed: 2e3,
        pause: 4e3,
        auto: true,
        preload: "visible"
    });
    $(".stop").click(function () {
        demo1.stopAuto()
    });
    $(".start").click(function () {
        demo1.startAuto()
    });
    $(".prev").click(function () {
        demo1.goToPrevSlide();
        return false
    });
    $(".next").click(function () {
        demo1.goToNextSlide();
        return false
    });
    $(".reset").click(function () {
        demo1.destroySlider();
        return false
    });
    $(".reload").click(function () {
        demo1.reloadSlider();
        return false
    });
    $(".init").click(function () {
        demo1 = $("#demo1").slippry();
        return false
    })
});
```

The error is in the part where it includes one of my css files, the one called "slippry". The error says: "Undefined function or method". My question is: Do I have to call this css file in another way to make the slider work? Do I have to change the path?

Comment: You need to include the plugin (js source) before it is called. The plugin is likely comprised of a js and CSS file.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to answer your question directly, I would first recommend that you use [Twitter Bootstrap's Carousel (slider)](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel), as you won't have to worry about binding your click events to controls. In addition to its robust design/extensibility that includes events.

You can fully customize the css to make the slider look like whatever you want it too... Plus the bootstrap package provides a very nice [responsive framework](http://getbootstrap.com/), and you should be using one of these anyways.